# GitLab cache sharing between branches

Tags: caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm trying to run job **A** and **B** on **merge request**. After a successful merge, job **C** should be executed.
Job **A** is used to install a Nodejs dependencies and push them to cache so jobs **B** and **C** can use that cache. On Gitlab side I'm using a shared runners. Please help me to solve that task. My **gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
image: node:19-alpine
stages:
  - install_dependencies
  - test1
  - test2

cache: 
   key: somekeyvalue1234
   paths:
     - node_modules/
   policy: pull

install_dependencies:
  stage: install_dependencies
  cache:
    key: somekeyvalue1234
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    policy: push
  script:
    - npm ci
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'   

test1:
  stage: test1
  script:
    - npm run test1
  rules:
     - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "merge-request-test"'

test2:
  stage: test2
  script:
    - npm run test2
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "branch-foo"'
```

For some reason the cache can be successfully downloaded by job **B** while MR is triggered. But after a successful MR job **C** can't find that cache. How to populate the cache while running my pipeline showed above?

Comment: I've had similar issue with GitLab pipelines, but I can't answer the question and my comments are too big to fit in the comment box. If you're interested, we could discuss GitLab pipelines in the [Git chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228186/git).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. It was very simple but I lost a few days by googling.
In **CI/CD Settings -> General pipelines** I unchecked the setting **Use separate caches for protected branches** and voila